# Return argument type struct Details.Prosumer storage ref is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) uint256

Tags: solidity, remix, arrays, struct

```
Prosumer[] public ProsumeArray;

struct Prosumer{
    uint ProsumerID;
    uint Pros_power;
    uint per_unit_rate;
}

function setPros(uint ProsumerID, uint Pros_power,uint per_unit_rate)public {
    Prosumer memory newProsumer=Prosumer({
        ProsumerID: ProsumerID,
        Pros_power: Pros_power,
        per_unit_rate: per_unit_rate
    });
    ProsumeArray.push(newProsumer);
}

function ChoosePro(uint n) public view returns(uint ){
    return ProsumeArray[n];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to return?

it seems you are trying to return the struct **Prosumer** in that case your return type should be Prosumer you can see in the following code:

```
 function ChoosePro(uint n) public view returns(Prosumer memory){
    return ProsumeArray[n];
 }
```

Comment: I want to access one element of the array. So that I can perform addition and subtraction of the element with reference to other uint values